# CentOS Virt-v2v conversion tool

Tags: centos, vmware-esxi, redhat, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to use the virt-v2v tool in CentOS for the conversion of virtual to virtual and eventually physical to virtual machines. I am rather confused after spending a day trying to get the virt-2v2 converter set up and working.

I am running CentOS 6.5, below are my reasons for confusion.

I am attempting to convert a VMWare virtual machine, and I an confused about the concept of a "Storage Pool". When I open virt-manager and go to the localhost connection details (qemu:///system) and go to the Storage tab, I can see that there is a default storage pool located at /var/lib/libvirt/images. Is this basically a directory where images are stored?

When I attempt to use the virt0-v2v command as follows:

```
virt-v2v -i libvirtxml -osd /var/lib/libvirt/images Windows7.xml
```

Where windows7 xml is an xml file generated with the Vmware2libvirt tool. 
I am told that /var/lib/libvirt/images is not a valid storage pool. Perhaps there is something I am doing wrong when issuing this command. Please forgive my ignorance, I am very new to virtualization and server management in general.

Comment: Have you tried "default" instead of the path?

Comment: I have, and now I am running into an issue with the Libguesftfs applience

Comment: so this particular issue has been resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the name of the storage pool, not the path to it. You can get your storage pool names with `virsh pool-list`. You should have one named *default*.

Comment: This is correct, thank you. I am not running into errors with the libguesstfs appliance